# Using python script inside for loop

Tags: python

I want to insert a python script, (which just print out input) inside for loop. Problem: in place of taking "i" as a variable - it just prints "i", not "string1", "string2".
I tried:

```
for i in ['string1, string2']:
    os.system("python scriptWhichPrintsInput.py i")
...
i
```

Comment: you are using i as a hardcoded string. not as a variable

Comment: i should also add, you shouldn't be using os.system to run other python scripts. Take a look at importing other scripts as modules.

Comment: I agree with Paritosh Singh. What is the point to call a python module using `os.system` ? Use `import` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use format or string concatenation:

```
os.system("python scriptWhichPrintsInput.py " + i)
```

Or:

```
os.system("python scriptWhichPrintsInput.py {}".format(i))
```

See docs for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) and for [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting)

Comment: Or with new f-strings `os.system(f"python scriptWhichPrintsInput.py {i}")`

Comment: Thanks @ozlevka . I am coming from the world of bash, so I would like to ask this: if I have string1 and string2 written in text file - myFile, what will be a parallel to "for i in $(cat myFile)...."

Comment: That's [not good style in Bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) either. The way to translate `while read -r i ... done <myFile` to Python is `with open('myFile') as f: for line in f: i=line.rstrip('\n') ...`

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this method lead to an appreciable difference in performance? I would assume so if you're not explicitly importing a module and performing a file lookup each loop....

Comment: This is a very good question. Want to publish it as StackOverflow question? Or I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure why you would want to do it this way, but here goes.

### The TLDR:

First, you'll want to parse the argument dynamically at runtime (not just the char 'i' in your string!) So try,

```
for i in ['string1', 'string2']:
    os.system("python scriptWhichPrintsInput.py {}".format(i)) 
...
i
```

- see: [the docs here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting) on string formatting.
- also fixed (I assume typo) on your strings by closing the apostrophes.

Then, I would assume, your other python script is some function, `foo()`, that takes an input, `i`, such as;

```
foo(i, *args, **kwargs):
    # insert your script function here...
    pass
```

### The Long Way:

This is what I'd probably do instead.

Rather than parsing a string representation of my script with the `os` dependency, I'd make the script importable (call it `scriptWhichPrintsInput.py`) then just make sure it's on my Python path (read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)). Such as,

```
# your scriptWhichPrintsInput.py file
foo(i, *args, **kwargs):
    # do something with your input...
    print(i)
    return
```

Then in your other script (as above),

```
# your scriptWhichPrintsInput.py file
from .scriptWhichPrintsInput import foo if your script is in the same folder, easy!

for i in ['string1', 'string2']:
    foo(i)
...
i # do whatever you need to do here!
```